# I have to read Coordinates of childs div in jquery and i want to sort out by x coordinates my code is below

Tags: javascript, jquery

The current way is providing invalid output.

This is the object i'm trying to sort through

please check it

```
   $('.childboxes').each(function () {

    var divs = $(this);
    var divID = $(this).attr('id');
    var position = divs.position();
    var left = position.left;
    var top = position.top;


    AllDivsCoor.push({ "id": divID, "leftcoor": left, "topcoor": top });



});

AllDivsCoor.sort('leftcoor');
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to write a own sort function like this:

```
function compareCoords(a, b) {
  if (a.leftcoor < b.leftcoor) return -1;
  if (a.leftcoor > b.leftcoor) return 1;
  return 0;
}
AllDivsCoor.sort(compareCoords);
```

DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ssjaor4h/2/)

Further informations about [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: thanks a lot.. awesome its working charm :) thanks alexP